# + char in file permissions

Tags: files

After executing the command I got this output:

```
ll /dev/

crw-rw----+  1 root root     10, 232 Jun  3 21:49 kvm
```

What does the '+' character mean ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means that the file has some more ACL entries associated with it. Use

```
getfacl /dev/kvm
```

to get a list of all ACL entries attached to this file.

Comment: it should be:  getfacl /dev/kvm